# Ruby's narray gem installation error

Tags: ruby, math, installation, rubygems, narray

I'm trying to install the NArray gem for Ruby to do some math functions. I'm running Ruby version 1.8.7 on a OSX Mountain Lion

When I attempt to install the NArray gem, it produces the following error:

```
instance of Date needs to have method `marshal_load'
```

I've googled, with no luck whatsoever.

Comment: I got the same error when installing it using Ruby 1.8.7. When I used ruby 1.9.3 installation was successful.

Comment: awesome.... am installing rvm now to update my ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to a change in Marshal format of Date.
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/266